# Desktop Bridge requires .net native tool chain, but how to use it in a runtime component

Tags: uwp, windows-10, .net-native

I try to get a JavaScript UWP app into the Store which uses the Desktop Bridge (some "older" parts). There is a C# UWP Windows runtime component (winmd) as a project in the solution.
Everything works fine and runs as expected, but when I try to get the package into the store I get the following error:

> Package acceptance validation error: Apps converted with the Desktop Bridge and that require the .NET Native framework must be pre-compiled by the .NET Native tool chain.

The JavaScript UWP App does already using .net native compiling (AFAIK the this is the default for JS UWP), **but how do I configure this for the C# Windows runtime component library project?**

Comment: How did you create the package? Have your package pasted Windows App Certification Kit test?

Comment: The package was created by Visual Studio: "Store -> Create App Packages..."
No it will not pass App Certification Kit, because of the `<rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />` entry in the manifest. But this is needed for my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer my question self, the resolution for this problem was to bundle the package manually after building from visual studio. The relevant information can be find here: [Desktop to UWP Bridge: Packaging .NET apps using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net)

Esp. this info: [image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Unlike publishing normal UWP apps, to publish an app converted with the Desktop Bridge, please fill out the form at [Bring your existing apps and games to the Windows Store with the Desktop Bridge](https://developer.microsoft.com/windows/projects/campaigns/desktop-bridge). Microsoft will contact you to start the onboarding process. Our team will work directly with you to get your converted apps or games into the Windows Store.

For more info, please see [Desktop Bridge Packaging Guide for .NET Desktop apps with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) and [Distribute apps converted with the Desktop Bridge](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-distribute).

Comment: Yes this what I have already done before. I was in contact with Microsoft, but no one could help me with this issue. Right now I have ported my runtime component to C++ and it works now, but i have other 3rdparty runtime components which i could not handle.

Comment: @DanielToplak As you are using 3rd party components in your project, I'd suggest you check the requirements [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare) and make sure they are supported to be converted. Also could you please share the email title that you've send to Microsoft and the App Name you've filled in the form so that we can help you get in touch with the team.

Comment: Zuo how could I share the email title and appname with you?

Comment: @DanielToplak You can leave the email title and app name in the comment. I will check the comment latter. ;)

Comment: Email title: [Req: 117012315214819]
App name: CAD Models Sales
Note: this app is not public available, it is only in our store for business.